# what is the maximum length/size of the command that can be executed in java Runtime.getRuntime.exec()

Tags: java, runtime, exec

I have a Unix command to send email. the command has from address, to address, subject and message body. The java Runtime.getRuntime.exec() executes the command when i have 2 email ids whereas, if i increase the recipients to more than 2, then the command is not executed. Can anyone tell what is the size of the command or the maximum length of the command that can be executed using Runtime.getRuntime.exec() method ?
Please guide me on this problem.

thanks for your replies.

Comment: Instead, you better show us what your input is for `exec` method, that would help to diagnose.

Comment: the unix command is 
/nova/bin/sendfile -f '<fromaddress>' -t '<multiple to address>' -c '<multiple email distribution list> ' 
-s '<email subject>' '<message body>' 

this is the input for exec

Answer (score 0):

[`Runtime.exec(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29) method takes `String` value as input.

```
public Process exec(String command) throws IOException
```

[`String.length()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length%28%29) method returns an `int` value

```
public int length()
```

> Returns the length of this string. The length is equal to the number of [*Unicode code units*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#unicode) in the string

An [`Integer's MAX_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE) is

```
public static final int MAX_VALUE
```

> A constant holding the maximum value an `int` can have, `231 - 1`, i.e. `2147483647`

Meaning, the `Runtime.exec` can take a `String` argument of command and its arguments with a combined length of `2147483647` bytes.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
My command length is 359 characters. but it is not executed. It does not throws any exception. when the recipients are just 2 , i am getting the email triggered. if the recipients are increased then email is not triggered. its not even showing an error. if i run the command seperatly, then the email is triggered even to n number of recipients.
Please help on this.

Thanks

Comment: This is incorrect. Just because String.length() is an int that doesn't mean you can actually create a string of 2147483647 characters, still less does it mean you can execute a command that long. It depends on the operating system. A limit of 8KB or 32KB may be typical but it's difficult to get concrete data on this.